# Is my polymorphism process causing a memory leak?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `TreeItem` class which has a data member with the name Container

```
class TreeItem
{
 public:    
 void setContainer(const Container &data);

 private:
    QList<TreeItem*> childItems;
    Container itemData;
     TreeItem* parentItem;
 };
```

---

Definition for `setContainer`

```
void TreeItem::setContainer(const Container &cont)
 {
   itemData = cont; 
 }
```

---

Defination for Container Class

```
class Container
 {
  private:
  std::string stdstrContainerName;
  std::string stdstrPluginType;
  Geometry* Geom;

public:
 Container();
 Container(std::string, std::string, Geometry* geometry );
 Container(const  Container& obj);
};
```

---

```
Container::Container( std::string strName, std::string strType,  
Geometry* geometry) : Geom(geometry)
{   
  stdstrContainerName = strName;
  stdstrPluginType = strType;
  qDebug() << geometry->isValid();
}
```

---

I use my `TreeModel` class  to  set the value of Container in the `TreeItem` object

```
void  TreeModel::SetContainer(const QModelIndex &index,  Container* Cont)
 {
   TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
   item->setContainer(*Cont);

  }
```

---

The `Geometry` which is data type to `Container` class has a virtual function with the name draw

```
Class Geometry
{
 public:    
     std::string stdstrType;
     bool bValid;

 public:
// Other Functions
 virtual void draw();
```

};

---

There are other classes which are derived from the `Geometry` class

```
 class Sph : public Geometry
  {
   public:
   Sph( float radius , float segments );
  ~Sph();
  void init();
  void CleanUp();
  void draw();

 private:
   float fRadius, fSegments;
   bool isInited;
   unsigned int m_VAO, m_VBO;
   int iNumsToDraw;
   SumShader shader;
   bool isChanged;
};
```

---

This is the process i am using to set the Container to `TreeItem` class.

```
 void WavefrontRenderer::AddSphere()
  {
    QModelIndex index = treeView->selectionModel()->currentIndex();
    QAbstractItemModel *model = treeView->model();
    TreeModel *myModel = qobject_cast<TreeModel*>(model);

    Sph* sphere = new Sph( 0.1 , 32);
   sphere->setValidState(true);
   sphere->stdstrType = "Sphere";
   if (!model->insertRow(index.row() + 1, index.parent()))
      return;

   Container cont("Sphere" , "SPHERE" , sphere );
   QModelIndex child = model->index(index.row() + 1, 0, index.parent());
   model->setData(child, QVariant("Container"), Qt::EditRole);
   myModel->SetContainer(child, &cont);
   delete sphere // This line gives error

}
```

---

---

Everything works as expected but I have few questions.

1) Since I am creating a new Object `Sph* sphere = new Sph( 0.1 , 32);` but not deleting it does it cause memory leakage?

2) When I tried to delete it after setting it on `TreeItem` I got Memory error

Comment: `Container cont("Sphere" , "SPHERE" , sphere );myModel->SetContainer(child, &cont);` -- Please post a better example, i.e. not fake code.  You are storing the address of a local variable here, where we really don't know if it is in scope or not when you are issuing this `delete` call.

Comment: Hi Paul i have updated the function where i am giving the delete call.

Comment: If you remove all of the code between the call to `new` and the call to `delete`, do you see any issue?  If not, add the code back slowly, one line at a time, until the error is duplicated.  And, yes, you have a big memory leak if that `return;` is ever executed.  You really should be using `std::unique_ptr<Sph>`, not raw `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Shouldn't itemData be of type Container* ?

Comment: Currently the code is working , with this line "itemData = cont;" i though that cont will get copied to item data and then i can delete Geom*.

Comment: I don't know, that strikes me as dangerous. You then have to ensure your copy constructor deep copies everything don't you? Otherwise you get a management nightmare in terms of memory allocation for your internal objects which seem to be exactly the issue when you try to destroy the top object.

Comment: Thanks o_weisman shallow copy was the case why i was getting error after changing it to deep copy it got resolved